# Access linux's terminal per pixel

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, graphic

I'm trying to write text-based gui. Is there a way to access terminal per pixel using pure C++? I read a one method, but it was SDL based ;[

Comment: What exactly to you mean with _'access per pixel'_ and _'text based GUI'_?? That sounds a bit contradictionary for me ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you imply by "Pure C++", but [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) is the go-to library for CLI applications (and there is a port for Windows called `pdcurses` )